# How to make radio button class with SVG in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have been able to make an SVG row in flutter but I want to add a radio selection on them but can't figure how. Basically this is my code and the attached picture is the compiled code in the emulator:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class GivingMethod extends StatelessWidget {
  const GivingMethod({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/momo.svg'),
            iconSize: 95,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/mastercard.svg'),
            iconSize: 95,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/visacard.svg'),
            iconSize: 95,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how\where you want the radio?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I want the radio to be right before the SVG. Like on this link [link](https://dribbble.com/shots/15426602-Add-Request) where there is a selection on Vacation. Of course instead of Text there will be a SVG